# Determining the length of a UTF-8 response in an ASP script

Tags: http, asp-classic

I have a number of PHP scripts that I am trying to port to ASP. These scripts query a database, and display the results in UTF-8 format. This works fine for PHP, but ASP seems to have problems with UTF-8, and IIS seems to have problems with content length in general.

On the ASP side, there is no simple way to get the size of a UTF-8 string in bytes. ASP only deals with UTF-16 and bytes. Given that VBA code runs as VBScript rather than VB6, I cannot make any Windows API calls either.

On the IIS side, the response gets truncated if the content length is too small, and the scripts crash if it is too large. But of course if I can work out the correct length, that will not matter.

I should point out that all other aspects of UTF-8 are functioning correctly. The scripts display the correct response, it is just that they do not have the correct content length. If I use only ANSI data, and the Len function to get the length, all is well.

Care for some code? Very well, here is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
<% @CodePage=65001 Language="VBScript"
Dim data
```

'   set data to correct UTF-16 value

```
Response.Clear
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", CStr(Len(data))
Response.Write(data)
Response.Flush
%>
```

Comment: Are you actually asking a question here?

Comment: Perhaps not explicitly, but I think the question pretty clear nevertheless.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to port from PHP to Classic ASP? Classic ASP is EOL'd and probably won't be supported in future versions of Windows.

Comment: Classic ASP is closer to PHP than ASP.Net is, and we are familiar with VBA anyway. I did not realise that ASP is on the way out. I understand that PHP is better supported on IIS too.

Comment: PHP needs to be installed on IIS, Classic ASP is there but it needs to be enabled on current versions, but both work fine. Classic ASP has at least another decade http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669020?wa=wsignin1.0 .   This is a useful page for anyone using Classic with utf8 encoding. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx . Also, if MySQL is your database, use v5 rather than v3 of the MyODBC driver if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

Number of octets.

EDITED - To explain my point

Wrong. **I was wrong**. Well, more or less.

utf-8 or not, Content-Length only represents the number of octets (the term bytes has different meanings in different systems) in the wire. Period.

BUT, what i was not seeing is that you are not sending the pure utf-8 data, but leaving to the webserver/scripting engine do the conversion to the corresponding charset/codepage on data output.

How to handle it? If you are doing it the way your sample code shows, you can change your `Len(Data)` with `utf8Len(Data)` with the following function:

```
Function utf8Len( text )
    utf8Len = 0
    ' Only strings with data
    If VarType( text ) <> 8 Then Exit Function
    If Len( text ) < 1 Then Exit Function

    ' Create an ADODB.Stream object to handle charset conversion
    With (CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"))
        ' Define characteristics of the stream
        .Type = 2 '( adTypeText )
        .Charset = "utf-8"

        ' Put data into the stream
        .Open
        .WriteText text
        .Flush

        ' Get the length of the stream without BOM
        utf8Len = .Size - 3

        ' Close the stream
        .Close
    End With 

End Function
```

For a .Net alternative this can be used

```
Function utf8Len( text )
    utf8Len = 0
    ' Only strings with data
    If VarType( text ) <> 8 Then Exit Function
    If Len( text ) < 1 Then Exit Function

    utf8Len = LenB(CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(text))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Did you consider using the StrConv function instead?

Comment: @PhilipSheard: In ASP, coding in VBScript, where do you find StrConv?

Comment: Indeed, I have just found out that it is missing. Your code works, so I am awarding you a gong. Well done.